# How do I fix a Kernel panic?

Tags: package-management, updates, boot-repair

I was trying to do updates and it only let me do partially. The next time I turned on my computer, it had refused to load and I got this error after a long page of info. I'm a pretty basic user, so I don't know what this is or how to fix it.

The last line of my screen says:

```
[1.146512] --- [end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,1)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: More details about the 'partial' or what happened on the session before the panic would help. However in your case I'd boot a 'live' system (such as Ubuntu install media and using the "*Try Ubuntu*" option) and file system check (`fsck`) or your partition looking for errors & fixing them if found. If errors were found & fixed, I'd expect next boot to proceed, but the problem I suspect is from your last session (*only let me do partial*) and is a consequence of unfixed issues; without details of this I'm only guessing though.

Comment: FYI: In last comment I used `fsck` which is a command; you can use `gparted`, KDE Partition Manager or whatever is provided in your 'live' system to do the `fsck` from your GUI & needn't use commands if you don't want to.

Comment: Yes, I would guess that is the problem. I didn't realize when it asked abiut proceeding ti make only partial updates that it would keep menfdom getting back in. I will make a USB to boot from and try that.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: I haven't had time to get back to this yet. I will post a status as soon as I can, which will probably be the weekend due to my work schedule.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: Never do partial updates. Come back to `Software Updater` at a later time.

**Note**: Your error message indicates a blown or missing /etc/initrd.img-* file.

---

**First, we check your file system...**

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Then we try and finish updates...**

At the GRUB menu, choose `Additional Options`, then choose a kernel that's one less than the newest one... ie: if you show kernels -24, -23, and -22, choose -23. Boot and see if you can restart `Software Updater` and finish doing updates.

Comment: Are you sure is `-f`? It isn't [on man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/fsck.8.html#options)

Comment: It is correct. `fsck --help` shows  "-f    Force checking even if filesystem is marked clean"

Comment: @PabloBianchi see `man e2fsck`

Comment: @Rinzwind on 18.04.3, `fsck from util-linux 2.31.1`, `fsck --help` doesn't show a `-f` option. [`e2fsck`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/e2fsck.8.html) does, I didn't know that [_**fsck** is a wrapper for the filesystem-specific **fsck.*** family of tools_](https://superuser.com/a/19984/500826)

Comment: mine does. I copied it straight from `fsck --help`. and mine is lower: `util-linux 2.27.1`